# Including moment.js in a mobile app

Tags: javascript, cordova, momentjs

Is moment.js supposed to work on mobile platforms? I am building something in Phonegap and trying to get it to work on a page.

Here is what the start of my page looks like:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/jquery.mobile.flatui.css"/>
<script src="../js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/moment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

I also configured requires.config to find it. Not sure what is going wrong, or is there something I am completely oblivious to. Any kind of pointers will be greatly appreciated.

This is how I use it in my JS code:

```js
var now = moment(); 
console.log("Playing with dates..."+now); 
console.log(moment().weekday(0));
```

But the calls don't seem to be going through.

Comment: we need more details here to be able to solve the issue. Could you set up a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) or add more context to your code?

Comment: In my JS code on the page, I do:
var now = moment();
console.log("Playing with dates..."+now);
console.log(moment().weekday(0));
This doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should work in *any* javascript environment.

You just need to format your moment for display.  Something like this:

```
var now = moment();
console.log("Playing with dates... " + now.format("YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss a");
```

Or whatever makes sense for how you want to display it.  Refer to [the momentjs documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works for Mobile apps using Phonegap/Cordova.
It's a simple 2 step process as below ([Reference](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/node-js/));

1. Install/download the library

`Prompt$ npm install moment
/Users/userName/Projects/Mobile/appName 
└── moment@2.18.1`

2. Start using it

`var now = moment(); 
console.log( "Playing with dates..." + now ); 
console.log( moment().weekday(0) );`

Probably your config has issues so it's a good idea to use it without Require.js initially.